# Get value of span id for hidden type value

Tags: javascript, html, hidden-field

I currently have a form that adds up the total value and puts the number inside a span id.

```
<p>Total: <span id="system_cost">&nbsp;</span></p>
```

I need that value to be put back into a hidden type value.

```
<INPUT TYPE=”HIDDEN” NAME=”charge_total” VALUE=”system_cost”>
```

Im not very good at javascript and am having trouble figuring this out so any help would be very appreciated. I need the id to populate inside the hidden type value.

[edit] sorry I put the wrong code in. [/edit]

Comment: It is much more logical to add a line of code to the function you already have. You now have a script that calculates the final value, right? Can you post it?

Comment: The code is too long to post. this is the file line that does it though.     $setSpan("system_cost", "$" + total.toFixed(2) );
}

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<p>Total: <span id="system_cost">&nbsp;</span></p>
<input type="hidden" value="charge_total" id="hidden_cost" />
```

**JS**

```
var span = document.getElementById('system_cost');
var hidden = document.getElementById('hidden_cost');
hidden.value = span.innerHTML;
```